# Should I ask others to put bounties on my own questions?

Tags: discussion

Bounties are a great way of bringing forward a question.

But when one does not have huge reputation that can be tricky ...

Can I ask people with big reputation points for bounties to be put on a certain question, or is that frowned upon  - and I should confine to my own means?

Comment: You have ~5000 rep, surely you can spare a measly 1% of it!

Comment: @terdon - I once got a 500 bounty on one of my questions and still the answer was not a happy answer. If I did that myself ten times i'd be broke... :) ... Now on the question: yes or no? i dont mind 'no', just need to know!

Comment: I think "Yes". A good person like [Mr.@JorgeCastro](http://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro?tab=bounties&sort=offered) may help you. but What question need to open a bounty?

Comment: @KasiyA - maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/551384/47206) when the time comes. But as I very much agree with the answer below, I will pay for it myself, and use other people's points after I have wasted mine. - [This](http://askubuntu.com/q/542240/47206) already has 2 bounties but the answer is negative...

Comment: [uh You are not alone](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475711/turn-off-keyboard-back-light-sony-vaio-svf1521dcxw)

Comment: I don't mind putting bounties on things if the question has been reviewed and is good, just PM me on chat or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can offer bounties of 50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450 or 500 reputation. A user with 5k rep who is unwilling to spare even 1% of their reputation to get their own answer noticed is unlikely to engender much sympathy. How would you ask for this? By leaving a comment along the lines of this?

> I really need an answer but I'm not willing to part with any of my thousands of Useless Internet Points®, can someone else please offer a bounty for me?

I might understand this from someone who has very little rep but from a >5k user!? That said, you can always ask someone you know in chat but I doubt that a user of your reputation begging for one will be well received by strangers. There is no explicit rule against it that I am aware of, I just think it is much likelier to backfire than to work.

Imagine someone begging for coins while playing with their 500$ smartphone. Would you consider giving them money?

Comment: You convinced me :) but then it was not as much my greed talking as my curiosity. Most of my questions are also based on curiosity more than on real need. - I realize I have a lot of points in fact and nothing much to do with, so I'll pay for knowledge ;)

Comment: @cipricus having said this, I'd be happy to help you put on sites where you have less reputation and I have enough to spare. On [unix.se], [su] or [english.se] for example. But just ask me in chat or something, don't leave a message to the world.

Comment: I will keep that in mind (if the need may be). The humorous part is the more I ask questions (and need answers) the more points I get. I got more points from asking than from answering.